# Python scipy minimize "numpy.float64 object is not callable

Tags: python, scipy

I have been trying to get over this error for a while and can't quite find a way to fix it. I'm trying to minimize a function, but whenever I call it I get the error in the title. I've looked at several other posts and have tried several different tactics, but no dice. here's the snippet in question here:

```
def objective_func(a, x_sum,y_sum):
    alpha_sum = np.sum(a)
    alpha_dot_sum= np.sum(np.dot(a[i],a[j]) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a)))
    return (1/2) * (x_sum*y_sum*alpha_dot_sum)-alpha_sum

def Dual_SVM(data,c,a):
    inputs = []
    for example in data:
        inputs.append(example[0:5])
    outputs = []
    for example in data:
        outputs.append(example[len(example)-1])
    bound = [(0,c)]
    cons_function = np.sum(a*outputs)
    cons = ({'type':'eq','fun':cons_function})
    # inputs = []
    x_sum= np.sum(np.dot(inputs[i],inputs[j]) for i in range(len(inputs)) for j in range(len(inputs)))
    y_sum= np.sum(np.dot(outputs[i],outputs[j]) for i in range(len(outputs)) for j in range(len(outputs)))

    sol = minimize(objective_func,x0=a,args=(x_sum,y_sum,),method='SLSQP',constraints=cons,bounds=bound)
    return sol
```

Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated. I know that the first argument needs to be a function and not just a function call, but I feel like I'm following the proper syntax. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: Where's the @+#+ traceback?

Comment: There's not enough information to replicate your problem.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?: Exception has occurred: TypeError
'numpy.float64' object is not callable
  line 78, in Dual_SVM
    sol = minimize(objective_func,x0=a,args=(x_sum,y_sum,), method='SLSQP',constraints=cons,bounds=bound)
  line 162, in main
    output = Dual_SVM(data,c,alphas)
  line 166, in <module>
    main()

Comment: I have validated that the objective function is callable using callable(), but I just don't know why minimize isn't seeing it as so.

Comment: constraints and bounds could also a problem.  The traceback (such as you gave) doesn't give enough information.  I'd also double check `minimize`

Comment: Check `cons_function`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The problem was that `cons_function` was returning as a float, and not a function. A `lambda` function in its place fixed the problem.